# error when query join from different schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

im want to join records from different schema but the result still error ORA-00907:missing right parentesis.

here is my query

```
select a.column1, a.column2, b.cast(column3 AS NUMBER)
from schema1.tablea a
left join schema2.tableb b
ON a.column1 = b.cast(column2 AS NUMBER)
```

fyi column 1 and column 2 are number datatype and column 3 is a varchar2 datatype

updated:

i updated the query but still error.  ORA-01722: invalid number

```
select a.column1, a.column2, cast(b.column3 AS NUMBER)
from schema1.tablea a
left join schema2.tableb b
ON a.column1 = cast(b.column2 AS NUMBER)
```

thank you

Comment: shouldnt it be cast(b.column2 as number) ?

Comment: @praveen hi praveen, thanks for the answer. yup correct i changed like what you told. but still error  ORA-01722: invalid number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `B.ACCOUNTNO` contains values that can't be cast into numbers, for example `123AB`.

What to do? Don't store numbers into `VARCHAR2` datatype columns.

What to do now? Find such values and fix them. Or, include `WHERE` clause into your query so that it avoids such values. For example:

```
SQL> with test (accountno) as
  2    (select '12345' from dual union all   --   valid
  3     select '123AB' from dual union all   -- invalid
  4     select '12AB5' from dual             -- invalid
  5    )
  6  select accountno
  7  from test
  8  where regexp_like(accountno, '^\d+$');

ACCOU
-----
12345

SQL>
```